# Access VBA: Unbound subform controls are not clickable

Tags: ms-access, vba, controls, subform

I do have an unbound search form, in which a listbox is filled with search results. Upon selection of one listbox item and click on a button "view details" the bound form RSdetails is displayed

```
30      DoCmd.OpenForm "RSdetails", , , "[ID]=" & selectedID, , acDialog
```

The bound form RSdetails contains an unbound subform RSmails. All controls in subform RSmails are unbound as well.

The intention of this subform is to establish a connection to a Lotus Notes mailbox and to perform a search for mails containing a certain key.

The subform has 2 dropdowns to select the view and the range of time to search in, 2 buttons (search and abort) and a listbox to display the matches.

Now if I open this form RSmails directly I can make selections in the dropdowns and click the buttons.

If this form (RSmails) is viewed as subform of RSdetails I can NOT make any selection. The dropdowns and buttons are enabled, but show no reaction.

What I already tried, but failed to succeed:

- open RSdetails in acWindowNormal instead in acDialog
- bind RSmails to a table which has a relation to the table RSdetails is bound to and definitely has a recordset with the selectedID

Any idea is appreciated!

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you put the subform with lock edition. Check the properties for the subform (into the form) and verify that:
- Can add? (i think must be NO if you have all content created into)
- Can Delete? (i think must be NO because only to read records)
- Can Edit? (i think actually you have NO and must be YES)

Comment: AllowAdditions and AllowDeletion is no, AllowEdits is set to yes. 

It would be no issue to put all the controls from the subform RSmails into the mainform RSdetails, if the subform should be displayed to every user, but:

Not every user has access to the connected Lotus Notes mailbox and thus I am working with capabilities. I created a table with user IDs and a function like canUser("mail") is toggling the subforms sourceObject and visibility. :-(

Comment: Which relation you put between main form and subform?? I think must be none in this case because you need filter from main form by some user properties.

Comment: The RecordSource attribute of the subform is empty. No relations at all, except that one of the dropdowns in the subform requests one value from the mainform to preselect a value, like me.dropdown.value =me.parent.BOUNDVALUE

Comment: The parent and child link attributes are empty too.

Comment: Have any site to download and check the problem? Dropbox or similar. Or direct to my mail juanmastercafe at gmail dot com

Comment: Export only the form with the problem, or create a new form with same problem.

Comment: Hm, I just created a new project, having one table, a mainform bound to that table and an unbound subform.. I set all the properties in layout/ design view exactly the same way, they are in my "problem-kid", but the error does not occur.

Comment: Now I exported the forms and the links to the tables, in which the problems occured to another new project and the error did not occur.

I finally created a 3rd new project and exported all tables, forms, code, etc to it. It looks like it was a hick-up. Everything works as expected in the 3rd project, which is basically a manually created one-to-one copy (exported every single table, form, etc to the new project). I will develop further and close this issue here, as soon as I am 100% sure, that it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: The problem was solved by exporting every table/ table-link, form, query, modul to a blank new project. The problem disappeared, the app works like expected.

Did not find the real reason, but according to above work around, it looks like an undefined hick up in Access.